# Cannot make request to gitlab running in the official Docker container

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am trying to run gitlab from a Docker (gitlab/gitlab-ce, latest) container using the instruction given [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/README.html).

Docker version

```
Docker version 1.12.4, build 1564f02
```

I first run

```
docker run --detach --hostname <myIP> --publish 8000:443--publish 8001:80 --publish 8002:22 --name gitlab --restart always --volume /docker/app/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab --volume /docker/app/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab --volume /docker/app/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

Then I edited the container's `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` to set

```
external_url 'http://<myIP>:8001'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 8002
```

Then I restarted the container with

```
docker restart gitlab
```

Now.

When I try to connect to `<myIP>:8001` I get a `(110) Connection timed out`.

When I try from the Docker container's host I get

```
xxx@xxx:~$ curl localhost:8001
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Logs (just the end)

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
2017-07-26_14:53:41.50465 localhost:8001 @ - - [2017-07-26 14:53:41.223110228 +0000 UTC] "GET /help HTTP/1.1" 200 33923 "" "curl/7.53.0" 0.281484

==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log <==
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2017:14:53:41 +0000] "GET /help HTTP/1.1" 200 33967 "-" "curl/7.53.0"

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-monitor/current <==
2017-07-26_14:53:47.27460 ::1 - - [26/Jul/2017:14:53:47 UTC] "GET /sidekiq HTTP/1.1" 200 3399
2017-07-26_14:53:47.27464 - -> /sidekiq
2017-07-26_14:53:49.22004 ::1 - - [26/Jul/2017:14:53:49 UTC] "GET /database HTTP/1.1" 200 42025
2017-07-26_14:53:49.22007 - -> /database
2017-07-26_14:53:51.48866 ::1 - - [26/Jul/2017:14:53:51 UTC] "GET /process HTTP/1.1" 200 7132
2017-07-26_14:53:51.48873 - -> /process

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Started GET "/-/metrics" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-26 14:53:55 +0000
Processing by MetricsController#index as HTML
Filter chain halted as :validate_prometheus_metrics rendered or redirected
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Docker ps

```
xxx@xxx:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS                                                               NAMES
67e013741b6d        gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest   "/assets/wrapper"        2 hours ago         Up About an hour (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8002->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8001->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->443/tcp   gitlab
```

Netstat

```
xxx@xxx:~$ netstat --listen
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 localhost:smtp          *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:2020                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:git                   *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:43918                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:sunrpc                *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 localhost:smtp          [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8000               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8001               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8002               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:2020               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:git                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:sunrpc             [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:43730              [::]:*                  LISTEN     
udp        0      0 *:54041                 *:*                                
udp        0      0 *:sunrpc                *:*                                
udp        0      0 *:snmp                  *:*                                
udp        0      0 *:958                   *:*                                
udp        0      0 localhost:969           *:*                                
udp        0      0 *:37620                 *:*                                
udp6       0      0 [::]:54611              [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 [::]:sunrpc             [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 localhost:snmp          [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 [::]:958                [::]:*
```

I cannot find what is wrong. Anybody can help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a `docker-compose.yml` which worked fine for me

```
version: '2'
services:
  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    ports:
      - "8002:22"
      - "8000:8000"
      - "8001:443"
    environment:
      - "GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG=external_url 'http://192.168.33.100:8000/'"
    volumes:
      - ./config:/etc/gitlab
      - ./logs:/var/log/gitlab
      - ./data:/var/opt/gitlab
```

The thing is that when you configure external url as `<MyIP>:8000` the listening port inside the container also is updated to 8000. In your case you are mapping port `8000` to `80` and you should be mapping `8000` to `8000` only

Read the below url for details on the same

https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#setting-the-nginx-listen-port

If you need to override this port then you can do that in `gitlab.rb`

```
nginx['listen_port'] = 8081
```

I prefer to launch Gitlab using a `docker-compose` file instead of commands, as it is easy to configure, start, restart gitlab

Comment: Why would the listening port inside the container be updated to the host port set by external_url ? Can you point me to the doc specifying this please ? Thanks.

Comment: Well, it seems that you are right: "docker exec -it gitlab curl localhost:8001" returns the right response.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Going by the docs, Docker gives this hostPort:containerPort option. Why is it that both should be same? I did check the link but i couldn't really understand it. I know that GitLab uses NGINX as a proxy server but i'm confused. Will really appreciate if you could explain it a bit.

Comment: Gitlab is configurable as such and some configurations they have to assume for default behavior. In this case they do this because that's the default behavior when you are not using containers. So to keep it same for those who deploy Gitlab on a VM instead of container they need to keep the behavior like this

Comment: Ok. So i deleted my old container and created a new one wherein i specified `--publish 8929:8929 --publish 2289:22` instead of the old setting i.e., `--publish 8929:80 --publish 2289:22`. I did not touch the NGINX port setting. Now i am able to access the GitLab UI from my local machine on port 8929 but if i do telnet to the same port, it's not working. Any idea?

Comment: Well if the UI is working the telnet also should work. But why do you care if telnet works or not if the UI is working?

Comment: Wanted to know just for my understanding. Anyways, really sorry for this question. It was actually a typo on my part due to which telnet was not working. Thanks a lot for your help Tarun! :)